# Django Reimport Module when tests.py is Run

Tags: python, django

I am working on a Django app that performs some class introspection ahead of time on all models.

This seems to work fine if those models are defined in models.py, but if I define them in my tests.py, __init__.py doesn't see those models.

The goal is to have a module level dictionary that is run once when __init__.py is loaded:

```
perms_dict = {}
for cls in Models.__subclasses__():
    add some stuff to perms_dict
```

When running tests, this code block gets run twice, the first time it does not see the Models in tests.py, and a second time the tests.py models are seen. Unfortunately, when a function is called in the __init__.py file, it seems to use the perms_dict from the initial run for some reason, and does not include the models from tests.py.

The easiest solution is to import tests.py from within __init__.py so it is aware of those models, but obviously in actual use that would not be desirable.

The Git repo is available at: git://github.com/philipkimmey/django-cerberus.git

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your core task here seems to be running some code for each model exactly once.  There's a good existing solution for this: `class_prepared` signal from django builtins.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/signals/#class-prepared

As for doing introspection ahead of time, this might be not desirable in some circumstances -- for example, when models classes are created dynamically.  I'd recommend just loading `models.py` initially and let the signal handler take care of remaining model classes once they are imported.

Comment: This is great, I'd never heard of that signal, thanks! Let me test it out to make sure it accomplishes my goal and I'll get come back and accept.

Comment: class_prepared seems to be a step in the right direction. I'm running into further problems that I think arise from either Django quirkiness (importing modules twice when running tests) or from my not understanding how module scope variables work in Python. Since using class_prepared solves the specific problem described above, I'm going to ask about my new problems in another question. Thanks again!